# How do I get my wife's PC to print to our network printer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, printing, printer

We have a simple peer-to-peer network at home. We've got a Netgear router. Both my wife's PC (a Windows 10 desktop) and my PC (a Windows 10 Pro desktop) have connected via a RJ-45 cable to the router. We've got an Epson WF-3540 printer, which is wirelessly connected to the network. For some reason my wife can no longer printer to that printer, although she's been able to for months, since we got her that desktop. (Both machines were purchased in 2015, although I got mine a couple of months before we got my wife's PC.) Every time she tries to print to the printer it always says that it is "offline". Last night she even downloaded the drivers from Epson's website, and re-installed them, to no avail. However I'm still able to print to it.

I'm thinking that the problem might be network related. If I brought up File Explorer in Windows and look at the network, I cannot see my wife's machine. I don't know if this is a separate issue or really a part of the problem. In any case I'd like to know how to solve it, please.

Comment: Your wife's computer cannot print, but the exact same computer was printing before. Is your wife's computer on the same Workgroup? Right Click on MyComputer, properties, from start menu -- or wherever Win10 puts it -- and check Workgroup (they  all have to be on the same). Also, are you using static or DHCP ip's? Are both yours and your wife's PC using DHCP or are one of you using static? Is the printer using DHCP or static? All of which could be the problem.

Comment: Also -- you might have to plug your wife's PC into the printer with the correct cable, test print, and then unplug it after initial setup.

Comment: My first guess would be the network type has changed, if windows does not see the network as a "Home" or "Work" network but as "Public" or "Unknown" it will disable SMB/CIFS and printing services.